# Samsung Galaxy Nexus doesn't appear under adb devices on OS X

Tags: android, macos, adb

I just purchased a Samsung Galaxy Nexus to develop apps on my MacBook Air running Lion.  I enabled USB debugging and plugged it into my MacBook.  The device isn't listed when I run adb devices (platform tools rev10).  Any ideas?

Comment: I was using a Nexus One USB cable.  Worked after I used the Galaxy cable.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your phone is set to connect in PTP mode, not MTP mode.