# Android adb (OSX Lion) does not recognize Galaxy Nexus, Jelly Bean

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb

I've been developing my first android apps on Eclipse installed on OSX Lion. I would like to use my Jelly Beans Galaxy Nexus for debugging, but the [Android Device Bridge (adb)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) can't find the device:

```
./adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

- The phone is in debugging mode.
- The phone is recognizable as a camera (PTP), but not as a media device (MTP). ADB does not work regardless of PTP\MTP setting.
- I have restarted noth the phone and the mac
- Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401049/samsung-galaxy-nexus-doesnt-appear-under-adb-devices-on-os-x), I've installed [Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/). The ATF recognizes the device, but no luck with the ADB.

Any ideas?

**Addendum:** I have [reported a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37059&thanks=37059&ts=1346842671) for this. Workarounds are still most welcome!

**Sep  5 13:28 UTC - Workaround #1: Dropbox:** I've moved the OSX Eclipse workspace to Dropbox and installed Dropbox on the device. The APK is written to `bin/`, and I re-install it from the Dropbox app after each successful build.

[image]

Comment: Can you connect to the SD card from the mac? Or is it only adb that is having problems?

Comment: It is recognizable as a camera (PTP), but not as a media device (MTP). `adb` does not work on PTP.

Comment: Actually I have the same problem on a Windows machine, also with a Galaxy Nexus Jelly Beans. No problems with a ICS device.

Comment: is your phone rooted? if rooted you could use adb over wifi

Comment: @nandeesh I will try rooting as a last resort. Can you please post it as an answer with references?

Comment: Which version of of ADT are you running? A guy in the android chat room had the same problem yesterday, and fixed it by updating his tools and plug in.

Comment: I'm using `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm answering this because my boss just had the exact same issue with his Galaxy Nexus, and we finally fixed it yesterday. He had an application, "EasyTether" that was snagging his connection to ADB and it couldn't be used anywhere else. Is it possible that you've setup this application, or a similar one that might be using ADB for you? If "Android File Transfer" works (it was working in parallel with EasyTether for my boss), then your connection is active, so as long as "USB Debugging" is enabled in your settings, you should be seeing a connection. Here's a quick how-to in the event that you do have "easytether"

**BEFORE** you plug your phone in run the following in terminal

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

If that fixes the issue, and you want to remove easytether altogether, you can us the `rm` command with the `-rf` flags to keep it from happening again...

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

Comment: Sounds promising - I have a tethering widget that might catch the USB connection. I will check it in the next few hours.

Comment: That was it! Since the old bounty has expired, I have started a new, 200 reps bounty which will be awarded to you in 23 hours. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for doing that... I really didn't expect that, but it is very much appreciated

Comment: You deserve each and every rep point. The problem was driving me crazy for more than a week.

Comment: just a hint, u can directly go ahead to /System/Library/Extensions/ and delete the kext file "EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext". You can do that if you have admin access and you dont need root access.

Comment: 2 days of banging my head...i read this an thought, "nah, why would i have EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext in my mac".....lo and behold- i do. And voila...fixed

Answer (score 3):

You can use adb over wifi.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) to do it yourself.

or there are quite a lot of [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bohlool.net.wifiadb&hl=en) on google play. But these need root access

Answer (score 2):

1. Try taking the usb stick out of the phone and put it back
2. Try taking it out of the mac and put it back
3. Try to put the stick in another port
4. Try to wriggle the stick so you are sure it is connected.

There is a long discussion with possible solutions here: [Can't find android device using "adb devices" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026948/cant-find-android-device-using-adb-devices-command)

Comment: Thanks! The USB connection works for other applications (Camera, file transfer) so I think it is not a cable issue.

Comment: It could still be a cable issue. I had a similar problem with my Nexus on my PC. ADB wouldnt work unless I plugged it into a USB2.0 port, on the back of my computer, with the Samsung cable (not the Asus one I have). Odd, but that did fix it.

Comment: @AdamMatan would you please try with another cable in another port? Just to rule this out as a possible cause. Its the most frequent and most likely cause.

Comment: Using another port worked for me... I tried all morning doing a hundred different things and everything was solved by trying a different port. Go Team.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a different cable? I ordered a bunch of cheap cables off of eBay, and the first one I used would not work for adb. It did work for charging and file transfers however.